# How to resolve message ' Requires: Commerce_checkout (missing)'?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have installed the [Commerce Checkout Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_co_pages) module (as the tar.gz file), as shown in this image:

[image]

Note the message shown within its description, i.e:

```
Requires: Commerce_checkout (missing)
```

Now I want to enable it, but I don't know how I resolve the `missing` part of the module.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module.

Commerce Checkout is a submodule thereof.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenprint it looks like you're using the module for which the info file looks like so:

```
name = Checkout Pages
version = 7.x-1.x-dev
description = Allow user to add custom pages to DrupalCommer checkout.
package = "Commerce (contrib)"

core = 7.x
dependencies[] = commerce_checkout

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2011-10-20
version = "7.x-1.0"
core = "7.x"
project = "dc_co_pages"
datestamp = "1319137230"
```

So as per this info file, you need to install "[Checkout](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/checkout)" first (that's why it shows "missing") ... and which is a submodule of [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

Comment: The .info file is irrelevant, you just need the machine name of the missing module to work this out.

Comment: @Clive With the limited info provided in [the first version of the question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/254539/1) (which at first was also tagged with an "8", though somebody different from OPer took the liberty to change the tag to a "7"), I wanted to be sure about what version the screenprint was related to. I.e. the module's description (note the 'DrupalCommer' typo in it ...) and version. Which is why I checked the info file first (while writing my answer), and decided to "share" my research (for which the content of the .info file was relevant) in my answer also.